# How can I hide/unhide a subform using ABCPDF

Tags: abcpdf

I am currently in a situation where I have a sub form inside a page of a PDF Template, with a group of fields wrapped inside the sub form.

I am using Adobe Lifecycle designer ES2 to create my templates.

Is it possible using ABCPDF tool(ABCpdf .NET Pro 7), to hide/unhide the sub form, along with wrapped fields through the code. 
I am using C#, .NET (4.0), visual studio 2010.

Comment: please explain it properly for better answers..

Answer (score 0):

Adobe Lifecycle Designer uses a different type of form than ABCPDF 7 uses.

See [this description](http://www.websupergoo.com/helppdf/source/3-concepts/8-forms.htm?q=forms). Towards the bottom we have this:

> You can use Acrobat to edit forms using the Advanced Editing tools available under the Tools menu.
>
> However, if you choose items from the Forms menu or toolbar, then you will probably find that you end up editing your form in Adobe Designer rather than Acrobat.
>
> Adobe Designer is an application which comes with Acrobat Pro. It uses PDF as an output medium. However, the way that Designer operates means that forms created by Designer are fundamentally different from forms created by Acrobat.
>
> For example, an Acrobat created form typically contains a background and then a set of fields. The fields operate separately from the background.
>
> Adobe Designer-created forms do not make this distinction. They use a separate data store to specify the fields. The PDF content is merely the visible rendition of this field specification. The underlying field specification is made up of chunks of XML embedded in the PDF.

(The word "Livecycle" was added to the product name after this was written, when it was still called "Adobe Designer".)

The forms supported by ABCpdf, also known as AcroForms or eForms, do not even have a concept of "subform" and so what you are talking about is impossible with ABCpdf.